# how to ignore directories but not the files in them in bash script with find

Tags: bash, find, grep

I want to run a `find` command but only find the files in directories,  not the directories or subdirectories themselves. Also acceptable would be to find the directories but grep them out or something similar, still listing the files in those directories. As of right now, to find all files changed in the last day in the working directory, and grep'ing out DS_Store and replacing spaces with underscores:

```
find . -mtime -1 -type f -print | grep -v '\.DS_Store' | awk '{gsub(/ /,"_")}; 1'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You answered your own question? Command you gave seems to work fine.

Comment: as an example, i run this when my current working directory is my music folder. if i added something to my itunes, it will report back that all the subdirectories have changed in addition to the music being added (because they have changed too). i want to just see the files, not the directories as well.

Comment: Oh? -type f will cause find to report precisely 0 directories.

Comment: I don't understand. `-type f` includes only the files. Do you mean you want the output to be only the filename without the path? (Reply using @Dennis for auto-notification.)

Comment: When I run it on my Mac under $HOME/Music, your command (modified to change the modification time to 7 days) lists only files that I've added or renamed (and the control files) - as indeed it should.

Comment: thanks guys, it seems i had forgotten the -f earlier in a loop and that was causing it to malfunction. a dumb mistake. sometimes posting on here reminds me of what i should be checking on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU `find`:

```
find . -mtime -1 ! -name '.DS_Store' -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

will print only the basename of the file.

For other versions of `find`:

```
find . -mtime -1 ! -name '.DS_Store' -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

you could then do:

```
find -name index.html -exec sh -c 'basename "$1" | tr " " _' _ {} \;
```

Comment: much appreciated. great info.

Comment: what would be the syntax for ignoring an additional string or file extension? if i wanted to ignore .DS_Store and .itc, for example.

Comment: @rick: If it's just a few, you can add additional `! -name 'foo'`. You can use globbing (make sure to quote it) and mix positive and negative assertions to narrow things down. By default the specs are anded together, but there's a `-o` operator and parentheses for "or" and precedence grouping. If there are a bunch of specs then a regex might be shorter.